# Cantor diagonal process in Ascoli's theorem proof

Tags: general-topology, arzela-ascoli

The proof of Ascoli's theorem uses the Cantor diagonal process in the following manner: since $f_n$ is uniformly bounded, in particular $f_n(x_1)$ is bounded and thus, the sequence $f_n(x_1)$ contains a convergent subsequence $f_{1,n}(x_1)$. Since $f_{1,n}$ is also bounded then $f_{1,n}$ contains a subsequence $f_{2,n}$ such that $f_{2,n}(x_2)$ is convergent. Iteratively, the sequence $f_ {k-1,n}$ contains a convergent subsequence $f_{k,n}$ such that $f_{k,n}(x_k)$ is convergent and $f_{k,n}(x_i)$ are also covergent whenever $i\leq k$ since $f_{i,n}(x_i)$ is convergent for all $i\leq k.$ As $k\to\infty$, then we have $f_{i,n}(x_i)\to f(x_i)$, we now construct the diagonal sequence $f_{k,k}$ convergent for each $x_i\in I$. The last step concerning the diagonal sequence $f_{k,k}$ is unclear to me, what confuses me are the integers $i$, $k$ and $n$. I need a clear and distinguishable explanation.

Comment: It's not the Cantor diagonal process, it just looks like it, somewhat. The Cantor diagonal process is to make something different from all sequences, but here it is used to positively construct a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

A subsequence of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ is just the same as an infinite subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. If the subset $A$ is written (uniquely) in strictly increasing order as $A=\{n_1,n_2,n_3, \ldots\}$ with $n_i < n_j$ iff $i<j$, then the subsequence is also denoted $(x_{n_k})_k$, but this can get confusing when we take sub-subsequences etc. as we are doing here (introducing more and more indices). So I prefer to just write $(x_i)_{i \in A}$ instead.

I'd write it as: $f_n(x_1)$ is bounded so there is a subsequence $A_1$ such that $(f_i(x_1))_{i \in A_1}$ is convergent (to $y_1$ say). Then having $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \ldots \supseteq A_n$ already defined (all infinite) such that $(f_i(x_n))_{i \in A_j}$ converges to $y_j$ for $j=1\ldots n$, then $f_{i}(x_{n+1}), i \in A_n$ is bounded and so there is some $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$ infinite such that $f_i(x_{n+1})$ converges to some $y_{n+1}$, etc. (recursive step)
This finishes the recursive definition.

So we get a decreasing sequence of sets $A_n$.

Then let $e_n(A)$ be the $n$-th element of an infinite set $A$ (in its increasing order). Then the diagonal subsequence is just the sequence $n \to  f_{e_n(A_n)}$. This is an infinite subset as $e_n(A_n) \le e_n(A_{n+1}) < e_{n+1}(A_{n+1})$ for all $n$. It converges pointwise to $y_n$ at the point $x_n$, for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

We are decreasing the index set of interest at each step. 
Let $a_0:=(1,2,3,\dots) $. Then let $a_1$ be the sequence of indices making $f_{a_1(n)}(x_1)$ convergent. 
Then $a_{k+1}$ picks indices only from $a_k$, making the required convergence. 
Finally, consider $a:=(a_1(1), a_2(2), a_3(3), \dots)$ which is a subsequence of each $a_k$, with finitely many exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you understand that we start with a sequence $(f_n)$ and recursively define sequences $(f_{k,n})$ and points $y_k$, $k =1, 2, ... $, such that

(1) $(f_{k,n})$ is a subsequence of $(f_{k-1,n})$ such that $(f_{k,n}(x_k))$ converges to $y_k$

where we set formally $f_{0,n} = f_n$.

Then clearly

(2) $(f_{k,n})$ is a subsequence of $(f_{i,n})$ for $i = 0,...,k$

(3) $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{i,n}(x_i) = y_i$ for $i = 1,...,k$

$f_{k,n}$ is defined for all $(k,n)$, so we can define

$$f'_n = f_{n,n} .$$

This is a subsequence of $(f_{i,n})$ for each $i = 0,1,2, ...$, in particular one of $(f_n)$. But then for all $i$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n,n}(x_i) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_{i,n}(x_i) = y_i .$$